# "Run time error 13 type mismatch" when trying to run a macro that copies multiple line text in to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I found a code from a friend when to trying to figure out to copy multiple line text in to a cell with a keyboard shortcut. The code worked perfectly for few minutes and then excel started to give me "Run time error 13 type mismatch". Here is the code:

```
Sub AllInOne() 
    Dim i As Long, txt As String 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
    For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count 
        txt = txt & Selection(i) & Chr(10) 
   Next 
    Selection.ClearContents 
    Selection(1) = txt 
End Sub
```

The debugger marks this line as error:

```
txt = txt & Selection(i) & Chr(10)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
The content is paragraphs that sometimes contain numbers.

Comment: What are the values in the selections? numbers, text?

Comment: Paragraphs that sometimes contain numbers.

Comment: I am not sure where your error is coming from. Could you give us a small sample of the data in the cells. I copied the code and tried everything but cannot replicate the error

Comment: What is copied on the clipboard before you run this? You have a paste but no copy. You are using Selection but don't select anything in the code so do you select your target data and then run this function?

Comment: Here is link to the excel file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/11005s8sp1dcw8b/sample.xlsm
I've created shortcut 'Ctrl+V' for the macro.

Comment: yeah I don't get it. I can't make that error happen no matter what type of data I put into copied cells (or selection range). Tried with buttons, formulas, pictures, comments, all different data types, tables, graphs, it all seems to work for me.

Comment: Did you use the shortcut to pate? I've assigned 'Ctrl+V' to the macro.

Comment: I can't download your document due to work restrictions. I have my own document I'm working from and yeah, Ctrl+V to execute the function works fine for me.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The text I'm trying to copy has bullets and numbering. For example, like this article, http://ezinearticles.com/?FX-Trading-Strategy---To-Win-it-Must-Contain-These-3-Vital-Elements&id=1297131
And excel thinks "-" bullets as minus signs and it shows #NAME?
Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: lol I can't make that happen either. used '1. text' , '1 . text', '1-text', '1 - text', '-1', '- 1', '(ascii0149 bullet) text'. I also just did hyperlink, dynamic db data references, a file object, signature line, word art, text box. I can't make this error happen. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Just how large is the body of text to be copied? Do you get an error on smaller selections? Excel 2010 can have 32,767 characters in a single cell ([Excel 2010 Limits and Specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)) What version are you running?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013. Is there any way, in the macro, that I can replace the '-' sign before it pastes the text?

Comment: Tested with Excel 2010 - Unable to replicate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying options, I found a simple solution.
I changed the formats of the cells I was copying data to from 'General' to 'Text' and it started working like a charm again!